# Local Multi-Group Spatial Dissimilarity error possibly due to weighted values

Tags: python, arcpy

When I run this code on a file containing 450 records, the first 260 records return no error, but the last 190 gives "failed script" and "failed to execute" python errors. Fixing code that works on some records, but doesn't on other records, makes no sense and I'm at a loss what to do.

## Calculate the weights field

```
arcpy.management.AddField(weightmatrix, "weight", "DOUBLE")
arcpy.management.CalculateField(weightmatrix, g_ESRI_variable_9, """1/(2 * math.exp((((!NEAR_DIST! - %s) / float(%s - %s)) * 1) + 4))""" % (min, max + 0.00001, min), "PYTHON", "import math")
if row_std:
    weightsums = arcpy.analysis.Statistics(weightmatrix, "weightsums%s" % ext, [["weight", "SUM"]], g_ESRI_variable_3)
    arcpy.management.JoinField(weightmatrix, g_ESRI_variable_3, weightsums, g_ESRI_variable_3, g_ESRI_variable_10)
    arcpy.management.CalculateField(weightmatrix, g_ESRI_variable_9, g_ESRI_variable_11, "PYTHON")
```

Failed script Segregation Index (Local Multi-Group Spatial Dissimilarity)...
Failed to execute (LocalDissimilarity).
Failed at Wednesday, July 26, 2023 12:59:34 PM (Elapsed Time: 2.44 seconds)

Everything I have is included in the previous comment. Thank you.

Comment: It looks like there's something about the data that `arcpy` doesn't like.  Have you tried isolating one of the records that causes an error?